# Emotional Depth

Tags: knowledge, wordplay, enigmatic-puzzle, language

- Clifford in his 35th book? (4 3)
- Shrek's pep? (4 6)
- So-called "Sidney"'s sadness about cookie inevitability? (Pardon my French) (7 5)

What do these characters display?
`#00C #303 #071 #016 #68A`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

These characters display their:

> **TRUE COLORS**

To find this, first find phrases that fit the three clues and their enumerations...

*Clifford in his 35th book? (4 3)*

> The 35th book in the *[Clifford the Big Red Dog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clifford_the_Big_Red_Dog)* series is [*Clifford the Firehouse Dog*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZTGiO9Ed6gQ). This gives us **FIRE DOG**.

*Shrek's pep? (4 6)*

> The fictional ogre [Shrek](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shrek_(franchise)) might be said to have **OGRE ENERGY**.

*So-called "Sidney"'s sadness about cookie inevitability? (Pardon my French) (7 5)*

> [*Sesame Street*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sesame_Street)'s [Cookie Monster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cookie_Monster) (whose real name is Sidney) may end up having **CRUMBLE UPSET**.

Now notice a recurring theme in these answers:

> Clifford is **red**, which can be seen in the letters of FI**RE D**OG.
>
>  Shrek is **green**, which again can be seen in the letters of O**GRE EN**ERGY.
>
>  Cookie Monster is **blue**, and the French equivalent 'bleu' (hence the OP's 'apology') can be seen in the letters of CRUM**BLE U**PSET.

Finally, addressing the five triplets at the bottom:

> These resemble [hex codes for web colours](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_colors). While these usually comprise six digits after the octothorpe, it is customary to abbreviate these codes to just three digits in length if each pair of digits comprises two identical numbers. In such a system, the first digit corresponds to red, the second to green, and the third to blue - we have to do something similar here...
>
>  If we read each digit as representing the n<sup>th</sup> character of the corresponding red/green/blue phrases we have already found ('0' as no character), we can extract the following letters:
>
>  ..T / R.U / .EC / .OL / ORS
>
>  In other words, these characters display their **TRUE COLORS**, a phrase which also has a similar meaning to the title's 'emotional depth'.

Comment: Was only missing the third clue, thanks for the  knowledge though!

Comment: @Auribouros The third clue was definitely the hardest - I was stuck on BISCUIT BLUES for ages - ended up down a YouTube folk song rabbithole!